# C# Trying to fill a 2-dimensional Object-Array with Objects

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating (trying to at least) a MySQL application in C#

```
        int i = 0;
        Object[,] oResult = new Object[i,Reader.FieldCount];
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            Reader.GetValues(oResult[i,]);
            i++;
        }
```

this part should fill the 2-dim Object array with the returned Object[] of the GetValues() method
however, i cant get the synrtax right. i is the number of rows, so for each row my reader reads, the array gets larger (at least i hope so) but i cant specify how to fill the second iteration. in theory there shouldnt be one, since i want the method to fill this whole row. in a 1-dim array this works just fine.

right now, i would say the best might be to switch to an list<object[]> instead of the 2-dim array and call it a day. even tho i think *maybe maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaybe* i could be required to have the 2-dim array

EDIT: GetValues does NOT RETURN object[], rather fills an given Object[] with values

TL;DR
how to fill a 2dim array with an array (ar[1,"this hole part should be filled*])

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a problem to *resize* an array, and you don't know *apriori* `Length`. That's why let's store the records read in a `List<T>`:

```
    List<object[]> data = new List<object[]>();

    while (Reader.Read()) {
      object[] record = new object[Reader.FieldCount];  

      Reader.GetValues(record);
       
      data.Add(record); 
    }
```

Then turn the list into 2d array:

```
    Object[,] oResult = new object[data.Count, Reader.FieldCount];

    for (int r = 0; r < data.Count; ++r)
      for (int c = 0; c < data[r].Length; ++c)
        oResult[r, c] = data[r][c];
```

Comment: welp, guessed a list makes the whole quite trivial. thanks for the answer